# AngularJS - Alternative to $scope in a factory

Tags: angularjs, service, scope, factory

I understand that we cannot pass $scope in a factory in AngularJS like the one given below.

```
angular.module("MYAPP", [])
.factory("SLNservice", function($scope) { ...
```

Am i right?

If that is the case, in the below example -

```
angular.module("MYAPP", [])
.factory("SLNservice", function() {
return {
    edit: function a(x) {
     x.num = x.num + 1;
     return x.num;
 }
}
});
```

//controller code

```
 angular.module("MYAPP", [])
.controller("t", function($scope, SLNservice) {
$scope.num = 3; 
SLNservice.edit($scope.num);
console.log($scope.num);
});
```

Would the console.log above return 4? or in other words, since $scope cannot be accessed in a factory, can we pass the scope(variable/functions) like above and get the job done? Or should we wrap $scope in another object all together and pass it?

Or is there a better alternative? Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$scope cannot be accessed in a factory.
we can pass the scope variables/functions to factory.

Factory is just like, service that, you can pass object/variable/function and you can get object/variable.

Regards,
Devang

Comment: I did not get it. If $scope cannot be accessed in a factory, passing $scope variables in a factory seems a contradicting statement!!

Comment: No. it will be passed as object.  ($scope as object in factory)

Comment: Sir! If I am not wrong, passing $scope to a factory has errored out, did it work for you? Even if it did work, then pls tell me what's the point sending it if it cannot be accessed(you said this)? I hope you got my query!

Comment: Yes. $scope passing to service was worked for me. but you can access variables like, edit : function(factoryScope) { console.log(factoryScope.a); factoryScope.a++; return factoryScope;}

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing things. Remember `AngularJS` is plain `javascript`. All javascript rules hold good in Angular too.

If you have a reference to a `$scope` object you can pass it anywhere. $scope is just a normal javascript object.

**What is not allowed is injecting $scope into a factory\service**.

In the example above you can very well pass scope object to the function by calling `edit($scope)` in the controller. Nothing stops you from doing this. The risk involve in this case is that you may hold on the the $scope object in your factory at a global level and singe services are singleton, the scope may never get released, leading to memory leaks. Therefore you should avoid passing `$scope` to the service function. Instead pass sub properties to the function, such as `edit($scope.user)`.

Also as highlighted earlier you cannot inject `$scope`. This is not allowed and does not make sense.

`.factory("SLNservice", function($scope) {`

Comment: So what i have written in my code is right? any other alternative?

Comment: Again whatever works in js will work here. You can pass anything. Also remember objects are passed as reference (hence its subproperties altered) whereas int, bool etc are passed as value, so the function cannot change it.